# Unit Test Adapter threw exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

I have created a test project it has a test function.

```
public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Logger.Instance.WriteLog("hello", false);
            int actual = Obj.Addition(4, 5);
            int expected = 9;
            Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
        }
```

i have created load test of this testmethod but when i try to execute the load test all test got failed and it show error
Unit Test Adapter threw exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

the error is dur to statement
Logger.Instance.WriteLog("hello", false);
if this statement is not there then load test execute successfully.
logger class is just writing log in a text file.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your `Logger.Instance` may be null - does this logger normally require some sort of initialization? Make sure you've initialized it properly before using it.

The stack trace should pin down *exactly* where the `NullReferenceException` is being thrown - maybe it's in `Logger.WriteLog`.